# Reduce memory usage when slicing numpy arrays

Tags: python, linux, numpy, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm having trouble freeing up memory in Python.  The situation is basically this:  I have a large dataset split into 4 files.  Each file contains a list of 5000 numpy arrays of shape (3072, 412).  I'm trying to extract, say, the 10th through 20th columns of each array into a new list.

What I'd like to do is sequentially read each file, extract the data I need, and the free up the memory I'm using before moving on to the next one.  However, deleting the object, setting it to None and setting it to 0 followed by a call to `gc.collect()` doesn't seem to work.  Here's the snippet of code I'm working with:

```
num_files=4
start=10
end=20           
fields = []
for j in range(num_files):
    print("Working on file ", j)
    source_filename = base_filename + str(j) + ".pkl"
    print("Memory before: ", psutil.virtual_memory())
    partial_db = joblib.load(source_filename)
    print("GC tracking for partial_db is ",gc.is_tracked(partial_db))
    print("Memory after loading partial_db:",psutil.virtual_memory())
    for x in partial_db:
        fields.append(x[:,start:end])
    print("Memory after appending to fields: ",psutil.virtual_memory())
    print("GC Counts before del: ", gc.get_count())
    partial_db = None
    print("GC Counts after del: ", gc.get_count())
    gc.collect()
    print("GC Counts after collection: ", gc.get_count())
    print("Memory after freeing partial_db: ", psutil.virtual_memory())
```

and here's the output after a couple of files:

```
Working on file  0
Memory before:  svmem(total=67509161984, available=66177449984,percent=2.0, used=846712832, free=33569669120, active=27423051776, inactive=5678043136, buffers=22843392, cached=33069936640, shared=15945728)
GC tracking for partial_db is  True
Memory after loading partial_db:  svmem(total=67509161984, available=40785944576, percent=39.6, used=26238181376, free=8014237696, active=54070542336, inactive=4540620800, buffers=22892544, cached=33233850368, shared=15945728)
Memory after appending to fields:  svmem(total=67509161984, available=40785944576, percent=39.6, used=26238181376, free=8014237696, active=54070542336, inactive=4540620800, buffers=22892544, cached=33233850368, shared=15945728)
GC Counts before del:  (0, 7, 3)
GC Counts after del:  (0, 7, 3)
GC Counts after collection:  (0, 0, 0)
Memory after freeing partial_db:  svmem(total=67509161984, available=40785944576, percent=39.6, used=26238181376, free=8014237696, active=54070542336, inactive=4540620800, buffers=22892544, cached=33233850368, shared=15945728)
Working on file  1
Memory before:  svmem(total=67509161984, available=40785944576, percent=39.6, used=26238181376, free=8014237696, active=54070542336, inactive=4540620800, buffers=22892544, cached=33233850368, shared=15945728)
GC tracking for partial_db is  True
Memory after loading partial_db:  svmem(total=67509161984, available=15378006016, percent=77.2, used=51626561536, free=265465856, active=62507155456, inactive=3761905664, buffers=10330112, cached=15606804480, shared=15945728)
Memory after appending to fields:  svmem(total=67509161984, available=15378006016, percent=77.2, used=51626561536, free=265465856, active=62507155456, inactive=3761905664, buffers=10330112, cached=15606804480, shared=15945728)
GC Counts before del:  (0, 4, 2)
GC Counts after del:  (0, 4, 2)
GC Counts after collection:  (0, 0, 0)
Memory after freeing partial_db:  svmem(total=67509161984, available=15378006016, percent=77.2, used=51626561536, free=265465856, active=62507155456, inactive=3761905664, buffers=10330112, cached=15606804480, shared=15945728)
```

If I keep letting it go it will use up all the memory and trigger a `MemoryError` exception.

Anyone know what I can do to make sure the data used by `partial_db` gets freed?

Comment: When you free up memory, CPython very rarely releases it to the OS. But it will reuse it instead of allocating more. So it’s very easy to mislead yourself tracking memory use this way. After the first couple steps, is the total at the end of each step increased by significantly more than the extra memory used by appending to `fields`? (Also, do you actually get a ‘MemoryError` or are you worried that you will?)

Comment: Hey Abarnert,  Thanks for the quick reply.  The extra memory use does seem to entirely come from the partial_db assignment and not from the fields; but I will try taking out appending to fields to be sure.  I am in fact getting a MemoryError  in the middle of the process.

Comment: Just noticed something: you’re appending a slice of the presumably giant numpy array to fields. That’s not a copy, it’s a view into the parent array. Which is why slicing with numpy is so fast and space efficient, but it also means a slice view keeps that parent alive for as long as it’s alive (which is forever, in your case). If removing the append makes the problem go away, try changing to `append(x[:,start:end].copy())`. If that works, that’s your solution.

Comment: Oh, of  course.  The  machine is a little unresponsive right now, but that sounds really promising!  I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: That’s the most fun thing about debugging memory issues—when you send the machine into swap hell and everything takes forever even just to kill the process…

Comment: Yup, that's where I was :)   Thanks so much for your help on this; I don't know if I'd ever have figured this out on my own!

Comment: 1. Did I understood correcty: you can't `numpy.memmap` to your `*.pkl`-files?
2. Can you work on *one file -  one os process" basis? Each proccess stores portion on disk and then accumulate everything on final stage.

Comment: I actually hadn't been aware of numpy.memmap; thanks for the tip!  The data is split into 4 files of 24G each, so at first glance they may be too large for memmap.  But definitely a good tool for me to be aware of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
for x in partial_db:
    fields.append(x[:,start:end])
```

The reason slicing numpy arrays (unlike normal Python lists) takes virtually no time and no wasted space is that it doesn’t make a copy, it just creates another view into the array’s memory. Normally, that’s great. But here, it means that you’re keeping the memory for `x` alive even after you release `x` itself, because you’re never releasing those sliced.

There are other ways around this, but the simplest is to just append copies of the slices:

```
for x in partial_db:
    fields.append(x[:,start:end].copy())
```